# ASP.NET MVC Partial Model Binding from Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, model-binding

Currently, I have a set of stored procedures which are called to populate different fields on  a page. I am calling the stored procedures from the LINQ to SQL class that I dropped them on, which works fine. However, it automatically generates (StoredProcedureName)Result class names which I have to work with.

Is there anyway to take a stored procedure and bind the result to multiple classes? For example I have a stored procedure that gets the information for a blog post. I want to bind that data into a Post class and a User class (for the author), however I am not retrieving all of the data from the stored procedure to fill an entire Post object or User object (the stored procedure only returns the title, content, and author name).

**What is the best way to handle this scenario?** I am open to changing the stored procedure but I would rather not have to return data that I am not going to use just to populate a full object and I cannot use LINQ to SQL to query the database.

Comment: Can you please post your stored procedure code?

Comment: So you want to bind, but don't want to pull the data necessary to bind.  Something has to give :)  Also, I would ask myself if it is really necessary.  It sounds like your DAL is in stored procs, so the interface is the params/returns from the procs, not your domain objects.

Comment: True, I just felt like it would be nice to have a standard model that maps more directly to the table structure so the names of objects would make more sense. So theres no way for a model to be bound while missing some fields even though they wont be accessed?

Comment: Model binding is the mapping of HTTP requests to objects.  This sounds like a "read" scenario.  I think your confusing the two terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partial of your DataContext and write a method that returns IMultipleResults, binding to each of your respective classes with a [ResultType(typeof(ClassName))], as shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399371.aspx

Or, you can store the results of the stored procedure in a variable and then LINQ-Select new instances of your target classes like this:

```
var result = dataContext.your_stored_proc();

var post = result.Select(s => new Post { Id = result.Id, Title = result.Title });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:
https://github.com/mrmmins/C-StoreProcedureModelBinding

This classes are using reflection, and you need include it in your project and create an instance of `Generic.cs`